# Fitting content horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale

I am rewriting a web application that visually represents data and would like to make the result fill the available width automatically (the previous version had a few user selectable scaling factors). I have simplified the layout to this:

```css
.bar {
  height: 25px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>column #1</th>
      <th>column #2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row #1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="bar" style="width:50px">
          cell #1
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="bar" style="width:150px">
          cell #2
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row #2</td>
      <td>
        <div class="bar" style="width:100px">
          cell #3
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="bar" style="width:75px">
          cell #4
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The width of the bars should be adjusted so that the table as a whole fills the horizontally available space (the left column should keep its width and ideally the height of the table should not be altered). The amount of columns as well as the amount of rows will vary.

I have full control over the generated html, so the solution may use a different markup (just note that the calculated bar widths are not limited to a few values).

**It is important that the relative lengths of the bars are not changed**. In this example, the bar in cell #4 should always be 50% longer than the one in cell #1. It should be possible to have text inside the bars and it should not be stretched (therefore, I could not solve my problem with CSS transformations).

The solution may use JavaScript. I think that I could make it work using only JavaScript by measuring the left over space and then scaling each bar manually, but this seems fragile and difficult to maintain to me (the given example is simplified).

Is there an elegant solution? I found it quite hard to search for this problem, so I might have overlooked something (usually I never need to ask questions as others have had similar problems before).

**Edit**: It seems that I wrote too much text and the actual question became unclear. I am looking for a solution that scales the bars inside the table from the given code snippet so that the table takes up all the available <s>vertical</s> horizontal (too hasty edit) space. The caveat is, that the contained bars should keep their relative lengths.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr?

Comment: I could, but only with the given example code. Is that really helpful?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the actual question through all the noise, but I can't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Baruch I could extract generated html from the old version and post it there, if that is helpful.

Comment: @1252748 I am not sure how to improve my question. The web application should create a dashboard of data coming from a database.

Comment: And what you want from us?

Comment: _"The web application should create a dashboard of data coming from a database."_ Yeah, I'll get right on that.

Comment: A solution using CSS or JavaScript that takes the given table and resizes the bars so that the table as a whole fills the whole browser window horizontally.

Comment: @1252748 That part is solved. I am not asking for a solution to that.

Comment: Set the width of the table to 100%?

Comment: like this or? https://jsfiddle.net/9c2any9y/

Comment: @1252748 It is difficult to describe. It does not suffice if I use the 100% width on the table. The bars should always take up as much space as possible.

Comment: well, yeah. you're statically setting their widths in pixels.

Comment: @bulldozer Unfortunately not :-(. The length of the bars must not be equal to the cells (only the longest bar in a column may be as wide as its containing cell).

Comment: @1252748 That is true. That part could be changed, but right now I do not see a way that works as I intend it to.

Comment: @Gordian I don't understand exactly what you want.

Comment: yeah it's still completely unclear. vtc.

Comment: @Gordian you said you want it to "fill the available width automatically" but then in your update you said "so that the table takes up all the available vertical space" - vertical means up and down, width means side to side. Which do you want?

Comment: @JoshMiller While I took time asking the question and proofread it before posting, my edit was too quick and I made a mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want with just a little bit of JavaScript and a slightly modified CSS file. This will calculate the number of columns (minus the initial column) and will distribute their width evenly.

```
<style>
.bar {
  height: 25px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
}

table tbody tr td:first-child{
  width: 20%;
}

table tbody tr td{
  width: 40%;
}
</style>
```

Then your HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>column #1</th>
      <th>column #2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row #1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="bar" data-value="50">
          cell #1
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="bar" data-value="100">
          cell #2
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row #2</td>
      <td>
        <div class="bar" data-value="80">
          cell #3
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="bar" data-value="75">
          cell #4
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then some simple JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var v, b, n, max = 0;
  var t = $('table');
  var w = t.width();

  // Set equal width for all columns
  var c = (80/(t.find('thead tr th').length-1));

  // Set widths of internal bars relative to the max value
  $('.bar')
    .parent()
      .css({width: c + "%"})
      .end()
    .each(function(){
      // Determines max value
      v = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-value'));
      if(v>max){
        max = v;
      }
    })
    .each(function(){
      // Sets each bar to be a percent width based on max value
      b = $(this);
      n = (((parseFloat(b.attr('data-value')) / max) * 100));
      b.css({width: n + "%"})
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but this is not what I am looking for :-(. It is not your mistake, because the question seems to have been very difficult to understand (although I tried my best to describe my problem before posting it).

Comment: You basically just increased the size of the table to fit all the available horizontal space. My goal was to extend the size of the bars until that point is reached (is that understandable?).

Comment: I think my answer resolves the issue. It sets the width of the table to 100% and then makes each cell an equal width. If a bar was 100%, it would take up the entirety of the cell. If it was 50% it would take up half the width, etc.

Comment: I found it very difficult to describe my problem, therefore, I found it difficult to search for solutions as well. Your solution, while I am being thankful for your effort, does not help me, because I am trying to achieve something else.

Comment: Lets say, the bars represent money spent on something (they do not, but I think that it could help to understand my goal). I want the bars to be as long as possible (so that the dashboard is easier to read), while still maintaining their relative lengths to represent different amounts of money.

Comment: @Gordian, I modified my answer to reflect the new information. We're still setting the table columns to be equal width - this is necessary to ensure that cell #1 and cell #2 are using the same basic scale. Then we find the max value of all available cells, then use that as a baseline to set the scale for all other cells. Rather than including styles on the `.bar div's`, we instead include `data-value` attributes that store the values we wish to compare. Some JavaScript finds the max value, then ensures all other columns are percent-scaled based on the max value being 100%.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer after I clarified my question! Now it does what I was looking for and even adapts to different data. I really like that you used a custom attribute with the "data-" prefix - a lot of people do not follow the standards...

Comment: @Gordian, I guess you should accept this as your answer so that people can reach the right solution.I Personally like Josh Miller's approach here :)

Answer (score -1):

Create a `class` on the first column you require to be "fixed",also 2nd and 3rd columns.Add `id's`to the 4 `div` bars so we can manipulate them with respect to their widths:
**HTML**

```
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="fixed"></th>
      <th class="col">column #1</th>
      <th class="col">column #2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="fixed">row #1</td>
      <td class="col">
        <div class="bar" id="cell1" style="width:50px">
          cell #1
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col">
        <div class="bar" id="cell2" style="width:150px">
          cell #2
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fixed">row #2</td>
      <td class="col">
        <div class="bar" id="cell3" style="width:100px">
          cell #3
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col">
        <div class="bar" id="cell4" style="width:75px">
          cell #4
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Next apply `100%` width on the `table`, then apply the desired widths to your three columns respectively so that they sum up to 100%.
**CSS**

```
table{
    width: 100%;
}
.bar {
  height: 25px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
.fixed{
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.col{
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

Finally,get each `div` by its `id` and set its `width` as follows,taking in account that 150px is your base here: 
**JS**

```
document.getElementById("cell1").style.width = ((50/150)*100)+"%";
document.getElementById("cell2").style.width = ((150/150)*100)+"%";
document.getElementById("cell3").style.width = ((100/150)*100)+"%";
document.getElementById("cell4").style.width = ((75/150)*100)+"%";
```

I hope that was helpful!

Comment: While it is not 100% what I wanted, it is close! You gave me a new idea how to tackle this problem and I think I can take it from here :-).

Comment: You understood my question while others did not - do you have any feedback how I could have asked a better question (e.g. I just could not find a descriptive title)?

Comment: I'm Glad i could help ,by the way you could use `px` values on your fixed column, and set the width of the other 2 to `auto`. Actually your request was clear somehow,problem is that its long, try to make it concise as much as possible.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem _and_ it's entirely based on fixed numbers _and_ it doesn't account for a varying number of cells.

Comment: @JoshMiller Yes, this is not a solution I can directly plug into my code, but it addresses what I wanted and it is easy enough to fix.

Comment: Why do you have 2 classes with the same attributes?

Comment: @Baruch Why are you being so nitpicky? MrShabana helped me with a working prototype. I would criticise those css rules and the fixed calculations in a finished product, but I would not expect that from an answer. His approach is adaptable to address these concerns and I am thankful for showing me a possible solution to my problem.

Comment: @Gordian Simply because it's bad practice. For you it makes sense and you understand it's wrong so you can work on it and fix it. But someone with less knowledge that comes across the same issue might not understand the best way to use CSS and then create bad habits.

Comment: Fixed it so no one gets confused! thanks